# Level 1, Think Different missing number

Tags: think-different

In the Puzzle game Think Different, at level one I'm facing the following screen:

> 16=619
>
> 15=825
>
> ?=143

What's the number correspondant to '?' ?

*(Note that 8 is not the answer)*

Comment: ...What? Could you give some context to what you're doing? Is this a math puzzle?

Comment: @Deltharis I belive this is tagged wrongly as a Minecraft question. I belive the correct tag would be [tag:think-different].

Comment: Are there any other clues? Have you tried 14? Why did you try 8?

Comment: I know it's called "Think Different" but maybe tagging your question "Minecraft" when it obviously isn't is too different.

Comment: Huh, 8 does seem to be the obvious answer (1+6+9=16, 8+2+5=15, so 1+4+3=8 should work), but apparently that's not different enough.  I'm interested in this game now.  Be back if I find it and get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I just found this question as Level 1 Stage 2, and the game accepted 8 as my answer.  I sat trying to think of another way to answer it, since your question said 8 isn't the answer, but since I couldn't think of anything else I tried it and it said Complete and unlocked Level 1 Stage 3.

Maybe try 8 again?

Comment: Considering the last Think Different question I saw was about the OP not accepting the right answer because they entered it wrong, this seems likely.

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer is 8. Maybe you are swiping left. Swipe the answer to the right side.